# New method to derive $\mathscr{E}=mc^2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, mass-energy

I was trying to prove $\mathscr{E}=mc^2$ using electromagnetism laws, here's my attempt :

Let's consider a charged electron $q$, the electrostatic field created by it is given by :
$$E=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r^2}$$
And the magnetic field (The electron is in movement) :
$$B=\mu_0 q\frac{v_e}{4\pi r^2}$$
Let's divide $E$ by $B$ :
\begin{align}
\frac{E}{B}&=\frac{q}{4\pi \varepsilon_0 r^2}\times\frac{4\pi r^2}{\mu_0 qv_e}\\
Eqv_e&=\frac{Bq}{\varepsilon_0\mu_0}\end{align}
And we know from Maxwell's identity that :
$$c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon_0\mu_0}}\Leftrightarrow c^2=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0\mu_0}$$
Hence :
\begin{align}
Eqv_e&=qBc^2\\
F_e v_e&=qBc^2
\end{align}
We know that :
$$\mathscr{P}=\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathscr{E}}{\mathrm{d} t}=F_e.v_e$$
Which means :
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathscr{E}}{\mathrm{d} t}=qBc^2\Longleftrightarrow \mathrm{d} \mathscr{E}=Bqc^2\mathrm{d}t $$
And we know that :
$$F_m=qvB\color{gray}{\sin\pi/2}$$
Using the 2nd law of Newton :
\begin{align}
qvB&=ma\\
qvB&=m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
qB&=\frac{m}{v}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{align}
Therefore :
$$\mathrm{d}\mathscr{E}=\frac{mc^2\mathrm{d}v}{v}$$
When I integrate this expression, I get the following :
$$\mathscr{E}=mc^2 \ln(v)$$
Where's the problem, is it in my physical interpretations or my mathematical approach ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: since $v$ is not dimensionless what is the sense of the units of $\log(v)$?  Your right side doesn’t the same units as your left side.  Moreover $E$ is the rest mass energy so unlikely to obtain this from circular motion.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero $m$ here is meant to be $m_0$ in the expression of energy. and I think that $\ln$ (I'm not sure) eliminates dimensions, so the units are the same (I guess)

Comment: no it doesn’t.  The right had dimensions of [kg][m]$^2$[sec]$^{-2}$ (log[m]- log[sec]) which is certainly not the dimension of energy.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yeah, you're right, which means this approach is a big failure for me lol

Comment: Note that you can make the sub $v=\beta c$ where $\beta$ is dimensionless which will help you with dimensions but will not provide a satisfactory answer in the limit $\beta\to 0$.

Comment: You need a $c$ in $\mathscr{E}=mc^2 \ln(v)$. It would have to be $\mathscr{E}=mc^{2}\ln\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)$. So you would have to integrate from $c$ to $v$ your $\frac{dv}{v}$.

Comment: Only on dimensional grounds, your integration requires to set one of the limits at $c$. Now, I'm pretty sure that excludes the non-relativistic expressions for $E$ and $B$ that you've used when the electron reaches the near-$c$ regime.

Comment: @joigus I got you now, Thanks, you may write what you've said in an answer so I can vote it up (that's a must :) ) !

Comment: The moment you write $F_e$ and $F_m$ your derivation stops making sense, since those would be forces that the electron exerts on itself.

Comment: saying that there is an electrostatic field and a B field is the first wrong statement. coulombs law is not true for moving charges.

Answer (score 0):

Only on dimensional grounds, your integration requires to set one of the limits at c. So that,
$$
\mathscr{E}=mc^{2}\ln\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)
$$

Now, I'm pretty sure that excludes the non-relativistic expressions for E and B that you've used when the electron reaches the near-c regime.